# Designing a self Recallable/Destructible email program

Tags: security, email, networking

This is one of my assignments and I need some help in getting started. The basic idea behind the assignment is that I have to design a self destructible email program that is capable of destructing the message after (n) time duration.

Speaking about self destructible emails, there are quite a few ones on the internet offering the same service. But what they do is, they just convert the email message into an image and store them on their servers. Now, they send the message attaching the image inline with it. After they receive a hit on that image (which means that the message was being opened), they simply delete the image and the inline image link breaks! BOOM!

IMO, that's not what a self destructing email should be like. Nevertheless, in my case, I have to take care of following points:

1. I have to do it for TEXT. No image, nothing else.
2. I have to assume that the systems used throughout the process will be UNIX based (I don't know how that is going to make a difference).
3. There are also some hints regarding the usage of various network layers in solving the problem.

**This isn't supposed to be done "in general".** What I mean by that is, I have to do that ONLY for one/two UNIX systems. Let me put it this way, all I have is two UNIX systems and nothing else. Now I want to create a program (in UNIX itself) that would do that self-destructing thing. I have total control of protocols and the network layers and I have to code anything and everything required at any level.

Comment: I know, I have searched stackoverflow before posting this question and I did stumbled upon that thread. But the context is different if you read carefully and I didn't find anything that would help me in designing this assignment of mine. Thanks

Comment: Without an external service (eg: a "trusted" third party) or a specialized client, this is impossible to implement.

Comment: Are you saying the assignment wants you to design an email client that is capable of destroying emails after a certain time? (If you're supposed to create a way to send an email that will self-destruct after a certain time regardless of what software the recipient uses, that's impossible)

Answer (score 0):

This is more geared towards the StackOverflow side of things but I have no problem getting you started.

The first thing I'd like to point out is that you seem to be heavily over-analyzing this. The services that have self-destructing e-mails which are image based are simply deleting a file after it is viewed. All you need to do differently is put that text in a file and get it's contents before deleting it. This fits well with the UNIX philosophy since so many programs already make use of flat files.

The part you seem to have left out is how you are building this. You describe it as an e-mail program and then talk about web services. Is this a web-based project or a program you are designing for Linux? Do you have to code everything from scratch or can you parse output from Linux utilities to grab the mail? These kinds of things really would simplify the process.

Comment: Okay, I went to the professor today and got a clear explanation of what all needs to be done in this assignment. First of all, I was assuming it wrong. This isn't supposed to be done "in general". What I mean by that is, I have to do that ONLY for one/two UNIX systems. Let me put it this way, all I have is two UNIX systems and nothing else. Now I want to create a program (in UNIX itself) that would do that self-destructing thing. I have total control of protocols and the network layers and I have to code anything and everything required at any level. Hope that clears the doubt.